# Wifi hangs on early 2015 MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, wifi, macos

It happens regardless of what network I'm connected to. Every hour or so, the internet connection will just load forever. Nothing else changes as far as I can tell, the wifi menu still says "connected" and "internet reachable" but webpages will not load. Reconnecting to the network / turning wifi off and on will always fix it. Early 2015 13" MacBook Pro Retina.

Comment: When your mac is taking forever to load pages, have you looked in the network preferences? It will give the current status of the connection. Connected or self-assigned ip or disconnected. What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Just to check if this is a connectivity problem or just Safari or other browser, make a ping to google.com (8.8.8.8) and register the milliseconds it takes, then, when the internet gets slow again, make another ping, register it and update the ping results to your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this site http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/16/fix-wi-fi-problems-mac-os-x-el-capitan/  . For me it doesn't work:(.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.